# How to save dynamic Javascript table to SQL using coldfusion

Tags: javascript, sql, dynamic, coldfusion, html-table

I've created a dynamic table using Javascript.  Here's my table outline:

```
<button class="btn btn-blue btn-block" type="button" name="addNames " id="addNames ">
    Add 
</button>

<div class="col-md-12">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="dataStorageNames" name = "dataStorageNames">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Phone Number.</th>
            <th>Remove/Edit</th>    
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>   
</table>
</div>
```

Here's my Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 

var i = 1;
    $("#addNames").click(function(){
        var a = $('#firstName').val();
        var b = $('#lastName').val();
        var c = $('#email').val();
        var d = $('#phoneNo').val();
        var e = $("<button>Remove</button>").attr("id", "removeName"+i).attr("class", "btn btn-xs blue");
        var e = $("<button>Edit</button>").attr("id", "editName"+i).attr("class", "btn btn-xs green");
        $("<tr />", { id:"dataRowN"+i })
            .append('<td>' + a + '</td>')
            .append('<td>' + b + '</td>')
            .append('<td>' + c + '</td>')
            .append('<td>' + d + '</td>')
            .append(e.trigger('create'))
            .append(f.trigger('create'))
            .appendTo("#dataStorageNames");     
        i++;  
    });
    $(document).on('click', '[id^=removeName]', function(x){
        x.preventDefault();
        var num = this.id.split('removeName')[1];
        $('#dataRowN' + num).remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Works perfectly, but how do I now save the contents of the table to SQL using Coldfusion?  I don't know how to reference the table and loop the rows to save the data.

I get an error:

> "Element DATASTORAGESPEC is undefined in FORM"

Trying to do this...

```
<cfloop from="1" to= " #form.dataStorageSpec#" index="i">
       <cfset variables.firstName = (form.firstName["a"& i] )>
       <cfset variables.lastName = (form.lastName["b"& i] )>
       <cfset variables.email = (form.email["c"& i] )>
       <cfset variables.phoneNo = (form.phoneNo["d"& i] )>

       <cfquery name="addStudentNames" datasource="TestScores">
            INSERT INTO tblStudentNames (firstName, lastName, email, phoneNo)
            VALUES 
               (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#variables.firstName#" null="#not len(variables.firstName)#">
              , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#variables.lastName#" null="#not len(variables.lastName)#">
              , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#variables.email#" null="#not len(variables. email)#">
              , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#variables.phoneNo#" null="#not len(variables.phoneNo)#">)
       </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: The form scope is not available until you submit a form with method="post".

Comment: That's the error I get when I submit the form.  Is it the right reference to the table?

Comment: You have no form fields in the HTML markup you build with JS. So you either need to create lots of hidden form fields, or better would be to create a JSON packet containing all the data in your table and submit that.